# Enabling AAD federated SSO for Google compute engine app

Tags: google-compute-engine, single-sign-on, entra-id

I have a Webapp hosted on Google compute engine. I am trying to list it on Microsoft AppSource. One of the mandatory conditions for listing is enabling of  Azure Active Directory federated Single Sign-on (AAD federated SSO) in the app.

Google Cloud platform supports SAML 2.0-based SSO. Hence technically this should be possible. Has anybody tried it and any experiences to share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to enable AAD federated SSO for your webapp as an application that are not in the Azure Active Directory application gallery using the steps mentioned here[1].

[1] https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps